# writing simple elegant mypy assertions

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I have some code that I have managed to suppress the mypy optional errors

```
    def column_element_to_column(ele: ET.Element) -> Column:
        name_element = ele.find('name')
        assert isinstance(name_element, ET.Element) 
        name = name_element.text
        assert isinstance(name, str)
        ...etc....
```

but its all getting a bit ugly.

Is there an elegant way to do the above? I tried cast, but that didnt seem to suppress the errors.

Answer (score 0):

actually cast does work...

```
    def column_element_to_column(ele: ET.Element) -> Column:
        name = cast(str,cast(ET.Element, ele.find('name')).text)
        interface_name = cast(str, cast(ET.Element, ele.find('interfacename')).text)
        won_type = cast(str, cast(ET.Element, ele.find('type')).text)
        return Column(name, interface_name, won_type)
```

all the assertions have gone...